# Why isn't working 'chunk_types' parameter in ConllChunkCorpusReader?

Tags: python, nltk

In the NLTK's [ConllChunkCorpusReader](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.corpus.reader.html?highlight=conllchunkcorpusreader#nltk.corpus.reader.ConllChunkCorpusReader) class, there is a parameter `chunk_types`.
I expected it would return the relative chunks from given text, but I don't know what exactly this `chunk_types` is for.

```
text = '''
Mr. NNP B-NP
Meador NNP I-NP
had VBD B-VP
been VBN I-VP
executive JJ B-NP
vice NN I-NP
president NN I-NP
of IN B-PP
Balcor NNP B-NP
. . O'''
```

After loading a `ConllChunkCorpusReader` as reader, I get results like below.

```
>>> reader.chunked_sents(chunk_types='NP')
[Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [('Mr.', 'NNP'), ('Meador', 'NNP')]), ('had', 'VBD'),
('been', 'VBN'), Tree('NP', [('executive', 'JJ'), ('vice', 'NN'), ('president', 'NN')]), 
('of', 'IN'), Tree('NP', [('Balcor', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])]
```

But I am looking for output with only NP chunks, as below.

```
>>> reader.chunked_sents(chunk_types='NP')
[Tree('NP', [('Mr.', 'NNP'), ('Meador', 'NNP')]),
 Tree('NP', [('executive', 'JJ'), ('vice', 'NN'), ('president', 'NN')]),
 Tree('NP', [('Balcor', 'NNP')]), ('.', '.')])]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A chunked tree is a tree with at most three levels: The root of the tree (the node `S`), with children that are *either* lexical items or chunks; and each chunk in turn is a tree of depth 1, with lexical items as children.

If you look carefully, you will see that your input has a VP chunk that has disappeared: The top of the tree is connected directly to the lexical items `('had', 'VBD')` and `('been', 'VBN')`. That's what `chunk_types` does.

You can visualize the tree returned by the reader by printing it or calling its `draw()` method:

```
>>> trees = reader.chunked_sents(chunk_types='NP')
>>> print(t[0])
(S
  (NP Mr./NNP Meador/NNP)
  had/VBD
  been/VBN
  (NP executive/JJ vice/NN president/NN)
  of/IN
  (NP Balcor/NNP)
  ./.)
```